# Javascript Map Issue. Parallel Parameters into Evaluate()

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Below is the code that I current have, which evaluates a function, inserting the range of tValues into "t" in the function. I want to also insert rValues for "r"

````
const rValues = Array.from({length: tValues.length}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * tValues.length));

const xValues = tValues.map(function (x) {return x1.evaluate({t: x})})```

essentially I need something like "function(x,y) {return x1.evaluate({t:x,r:y})}"
but I know that map doesn't do this that way.
````

Comment: What do you need the `rValues` for? If nothing else, you could just move the random number generation into the `tValues.map(…)` callback.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a `zip` or `zipWith` function